# Difference between declaring a List statement

Tags: list, collection, compile-error

I am curious to know the difference between these two List statements one using curly braces and other one parenthesis. Any thoughts please. Thanks.

```
List<BPSyncConfiguration__c> bps = new List<BPSyncConfiguration__c> {};
List<BPSyncConfiguration__c> bpss = new List<BPSyncConfiguration__c> ();
```

Comment: More examples and comments - [Collection initialization](https://force201.wordpress.com/2010/04/12/collection-initialization/).

Comment: Thanks @KeithC. I have used your blog as a bible for most of my coding. Definitely will take a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<BPSyncConfiguration__c> bps = new List<BPSyncConfiguration__c> {
                                      new BPSyncConfiguration__c(Name = 'Test Name 1'),
                                      new BPSyncConfiguration__c(Name = 'Test Name 2')
}; // We can pass multiple records here
List<BPSyncConfiguration__c> bpss = new List<BPSyncConfiguration__c> (bps); // We can pass another list here
```

---

We can use add method for both the above list i.e. **bps, bpss**

```
BPSyncConfiguration__c bp1 = new BPSyncConfiguration__c(F_SalesOrg__c = 'test'); 
bps.add(bp1);
BPSyncConfiguration__c bp2 = new BPSyncConfiguration__c(F_SalesOrg__c = 'test'); 
bpss.add(bp2);
```

Comment: Is this valid to add records to the second format of list above? For example, BPSyncConfiguration__c bp1 = new BPSyncConfiguration__c(F_SalesOrg__c = 'test'); bpss.add(bp1);

Comment: Yes, We can use add `BPSyncConfiguration__c bp1 = new BPSyncConfiguration__c(F_SalesOrg__c = 'test'); bpss.add(bp1);` and for first list as wll

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're interested in C# so:

By declaring your variable like in the first example, you're leveraging  the "object initializer" syntax. By doing this, the compiler invokes the `List`'s Add method for every object in between the curly braces (if any), AFTER the `List`'s pulic, parameter-less constructor has been executed.
Furthermore you can also do this with any type of object, not just for collections. I.e. you could initialize an object like this:

`Person john = new Person { Name = "John" };`

With the second type of initialization, you are constructing your object by directly invoking its public, parameter-less constructor and nothing more.

In both cases, it is totally possible (and legal) to subsequently invoke `Add()` or any other method/property of the object.